# Why should fail method exist in the monad type class?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, monads, do-notation

So I have this line of code:

```
[Nothing] >>= \(Just x) -> [x]
```

which of course gives exception, because the pattern doesn't match Nothing.

On the other hand, this code gives a different result, []:

```
do
  Just x <- [Nothing]
  return x
```

As I see it, they should produce the same result, because do-blocks should be desugared into using (>>=) and return. But this is not the case, making do-notation a feature rather than a syntactic sugar.

I know that fail exists in the monad type class and I know that it is called when a pattern matching fails in a do-block, but I can't understand why it is a wanted behavior that should be different than using normal monad operations.

So my questions is - why should the fail method exist at all?

Comment: It's still syntactic sugar, the sugar is just a little bit sweeter than you were thinking.

Comment: If it really _is_ a syntactic sugar, then how would it be desugared into using bind and return?

Comment: The [Haskell Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14) has the definitive answer to that.

Answer (score 2):

Code such as

```
\(Just x) -> ...
```

denotes a function. There's only one way to use such a value: apply it to some argument. When said argument does not match the pattern (e.g. is `Nothing`) application is impossible, and the only general option is to raise a runtime error/exception.

Instead, when in a `do`-block, we have a type class around: a monad. Such class could, in theory, be extended to provide a behavior for such cases. Indeed, the designers of Haskell decided to add a `fail` method just for this case.

Whether the choice was good or bad can be controversial. Just to present another design option, the `Monad` class could have been designed without `fail`, and blocks such as

```
do ... 
   Just x <- ...
   ...
```

could have been forbidden, or made to require a special `MonadFail` subclass of Monad. Erroring out is also a choice, but we like to write e.g.

```
catMaybes xs = do Just x <- xs
                  return x
-- or
catMaybes xs = [ x | Just x <- xs ]
```

to discard `Nothing`s from a list.

Comment: There is also a possibility which would work even beyond `do` notation: make all pattern matches that we can't prove terminate implicitly end with `_ -> patternMatchFail "Line number"`and then make `class PatternMatchFailable pmf where patternMatchFail :: String -> pmf` . Anything which is not part of that class is caught as a compiler error. (Note that it's the *output* type, not the input type, which says whether the pattern match can fail.)

Comment: I don't understand why it should have a different behavior at all.

Comment: @ChrisDrost That would break referential transparency (in the same way the current translation using `fail` regrettably already does with particular implementations of `Monad`): inlining a definition would change the line number in a way observable from within the program.

Comment: @DanielWagner: Interesting point, but I'm not sure it's "referential transparency" you're talking about: I believe you're expecting two functions with the exact same definitions to be exactly the same function independent of where that code is written whereas this approach says they are not always, because of implicitly-inserted lines of code. But those lines could at present be explicitly inserted by a preprocessor, so there's no real *semantic* difference at the Haskell level.

Comment: @ChrisDrost It is referential transparency. Referential transparency says you can replace a value with its definition and get the same result; but you cannot do this, because if you inline a definition that has a partial pattern, GHC will produce code that passes a different value to `fail`.

Comment: @DanielWagner Yeah, no, I don't find much value in that. I don't complain that `let x = 3 + 3 in x * x` violates referential transparency merely because it produces a number distinct from `3 + 3 * 3 + 3`. Referential transparency is **semantic**, not **syntactic**. The fact is, you *can* replace a value with its definition and get the same result, but the "definition" is not literally what you've written due to syntactic sugar. The claim that syntactic sugar (whether that sugar is operator-notation or implicit line numbers) amounts to a violation of referential transparency just seems silly.

Comment: @ChrisDrost I agree that referential transparency is about semantically replacing a variable with its definition. I claim that replacing `let foo = do { False <- return True; return () } in foo` with `let foo = do { False <- return True; return () } in do { False <- return True; return () }` _is_ a semantic replacement, and produces a different result in GHC. Because you cannot safely do this kind of replacement, you throw away a very powerful reasoning tool and a very practical and commonly-used refactoring tool.